# Need some help pushing a button programatically with javascript

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I want to push a button programatically in javascript, just once, by pasting javascript into the address bar.

Are there any code samples that can teach me how to do this?

Comment: ahh you mean XSS, I'm not sure if anyone will help you make something like that.

Comment: XSS. I've never heard of it. Going to look it up now. Why wouldn't people help with something like this?

Comment: @Mihai: No, he doesn't mean XSS.  He means a bookmarklet.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: good sites have nothing to fear from XSS i think

Comment: After looking it up and seeing the first result saying "Cross-site scripting (XSS) is a type of computer security vulnerability" I understand now. I was going to use it for testing a simple site I'm making because I don't want to manually have to wait for the page to load and push the button myself. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executing JavaScript from the address bar is known as a bookmarklet.  Typically you put your JavaScript between the statements `javascript:` and `void 0`.  Yours would look like this:

```
javascript: document.getElementById("someButtonId").click(); void 0;
```

This will only work for an actual button.  Ie, one of:

```
<button>Click Me</button>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" />
<input type="submit" value="Click Me" />
<input type="image" src="button.png" value="Click Me" />
```

Comment: What does the void 0 do at the end? If you tell me it stops the page trying to load (and thus blanking) then I will be a very happy man. :)

Comment: @Chris void 0 returns undefined. If it returns undefined it doesnt redirect or load anywhere

Comment: @raynos, @gilly3: thanks both. I've learnt something cool and new today. This makes me happy. Now to go update the bookmarklets I have doing stupid things. :)

Answer (score 1):

Its a borderline answer since its just an example with comments but hopefully it will help...

I use the following to log into the websites that we build with a single click:

```
javascript:document.forms[0].username.value = 'username'; document.forms[0].password.value = 'password'; document.forms[0].submit();
```

The key really is that you start with `javascript:` to tell the browser that what follows is javascript and then put in javascript. In the example I've got its a very simple form submission having filled in two fields.

I believe the javascript is run in the context of the page so if you have something like jQuery then I would have thought you should be able to do something like:

```
javascript:$('#mybutton').click();
```